# mystery files in All My Files

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a brand new MacBook Air, have not saved any files to it yet.  But I just noticed there are files in AllMyFiles dating back to 1997.  Are they "borrowed" from the iCloud?  Although they are not arranged in folders like in the iCloud, the ones I have opened are also  in iCloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can answer this question for yourself. In the `All My Files` view, right click one of the files and choose `Get Info`. The window which opens when you do that has a `Where:` field. For a file in iCloud, the `Where:` field says `iCloud Drive`.

Comment: That is very interesting.  I am concerned that having all these files "in residence" will clutter up my Hard Drive, which is why they were in the Cloud.  If I delete them from All My Files, will they disappear from the Cloud?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/152028/149185 for an explanation of how iCloud drive works.